# How I divide my data in intervals with almost the same amount of data?

Tags: statistics, interval-arithmetic

I have data (6 millions of numbers) and I want to divide my data by intervals (range of number). Each interval should have almost the same amount of data.

I know the way for finding intervals with ranges equals between themselves([as here](http://daphne.palomar.edu/stat/wpclassinterval.html)). But I want that  each interval defined have the same amount of data

What's the process or formula for finding that?

**UPDATE**

I need to do a manual calculus. I haven't software as Matlab or SPSS. The 6 millions of number is stored in a table of database. I going to use PL/SQL.

Comment: This is quite vague. What kind of data do you have? What kind of intervals are you trying make?

Comment: I had spoken about this intervals...http://daphne.palomar.edu/stat/wpclassinterval.html

Comment: @CesarMiguel so why don't you just follow the steps outlined in that link??

Comment: It sounds like you want quantiles of some sort. But your real problem is how to divide 6 million numbers into quantiles using no software except your database. Perhaps you should be asking this question on a site that gives advice on using database software, including SQL; perhaps http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hmm, maybe not http://dba.stackexchange.com/ after all; questions like these seem to go to regular StackOverflow, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79688/calculating-percentile-rankings-in-ms-sql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906283/t-sql-calculating-the-nth-percentile-value-from-column. You might want to look up the documentation of NTILE (though I don't know if that's in your version of SQL).

Comment: @David K NTILE is the sentence that some guys suggest me...Regrettably these guys (from statics team...) didn't know how was intern calculus on this sentence...

Comment: @BruceET I have to do ETL process. I'm doing "Load process" and should do on database :(

Comment: Well, you asked for the 'process or formula' to do what you want.  And you have a couple of answers how to do it.  Now you are mentioning artificial barriers why not to do what is necessary. Maybe your DB program will do it, maybe not. If not, and if the task is important, then maybe checking out R or python or something that _will_ do the job is your logical next step. Felice Navidad!

Comment: You can get R statistical software free of charge from `r-project.org`. Excellent quality. Open source. Available for Windows, Mac, Linux, etc. platforms. Should easily interface with your favorite database software. Lots of helpful volunteer blogs online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your numbers (sorting 6 million numbers in something like matlab should take a fraction of a second).  Then take the first million, the second million, etc.

Comment: It's very simple solution. In my case for finding size of intervals (_n_) I will divide total rows (6 millions aprox.) with total of intervals obtaining _r_. for my next load process I will execute _n_ times selecting _r_ rows. For my query have low cost I will use pagination in Oracle ([like here](https://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/))

Answer (score 0):

If you want four intervals with approximately the same number of observations in each, then use the sample *quartiles* as the five 'bin' boundaries. This idea generalizes. For example, if you want 10 bins, use deciles. And so on.

Different software
packages use (slightly) different rules for finding quantiles, especially
if there are observations with tied values. However, because you have very
large samples, and only want bins with 'almost' equal numbers of observations,
these differences should not be a problem.

If you
are going to use this binning as the basis for making a histogram, you need
to be very careful how you interpret the vertical scale of the histogram.
It needs to be a 'density' scale, not a 'frequency' scale. The fundamental
principle of a histogram is that each observation out of $n$ is represented
by $1/n$th of the total area under the histogram.

Here is an example with a million simulated observations from a gamma
distribution with shape parameter 10 and rate parameter 0.01 (thus mean 1000).
Each of the 10 bars of the resulting histogram represents 100,000 observations.
This is *not* the style of histogram one would use for an ordinary data
summary. It is contrived to illustrate your idea of bins with equal counts.

In R statistical software, the `hist` parameter `print=F` gives a printout
of various characteristics of the histogram, some of which I have shown.
(Intensities are used to make bars of the proper heights, so that each of the 10
bars has the same area.)

```
 n = 10^6; x = rgamma(n, 10, 1/100)
 bin.bdy = quantile(x, seq(1:9)/10)
 hist(x, br=c(min(x), bin.bdy, max(x)), col="wheat")
```

[image]

```
hist(x, br=c(min(x), bin.bdy, max(x)), plot=F)
$breaks
                10%       20%       30%       40%       50%       60%       70%       80%       90%           
 113.1149  621.9300  728.9403  813.3358  890.6540  966.7731 1047.5072 1138.7230 1251.9731 1420.9409 3292.5520 

$counts
## 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000

$intensities
         10%          20%          30%          40%          50%          60%          70%          80%          90% 
0.0001965351 0.0009344897 0.0011848970 0.0012933562 0.0013137310 0.0012386336     0.0010963020 0.0008830011 0.0005918289 0.0000534299
```

*Note:* Technically, the minimum and the maximum are the 0th and 100th
quantiles, respectively. I had to treat them separately here to avoid
error messages, which I suppose to be due to tiny errors in floating point
arithmetic for this very unusual style of histogram.

Comment: One detail: I think quartiles give you four bins and deciles give you 10 bins.

Comment: @DavidK: Right, I was thinking _boundaries_, not bins. Realized that when I did the example. Fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for explain me. Regrettably for this task my company don't let me using R :(